# How can I determine the volume name of the default boot disk from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I have some shell scripts that need to access paths under `/Volumes/` e.g. `/Volumes/MyDisk/tmp/foo.json`. Right now the scripts have hardcoded volume names. I would like to make them portable so they run correctly on my various machines, all of which have different disk names for the boot volume.

Can anyone post a reliable method for getting the disk name of the system on a modern macOS system? (13.0.1 as of this writing)

Comment: Why not access it directly, under `/`? For the system volume, all that's under `/Volumes` is a symbolic link to that anyway (run `ls -l /Volumes` to see what I mean).

Comment: Because on a system with multiple attached disks (USB, Thunderbolt, etc) there will be multiple entries under `/Volumes` @GordonDavisson

Comment: But `/` will always be the system volume. That is, `/Volumes/WhateverTheStartupVolumeIs/path/to/some/file` is equivalent to just `/path/to/some/file`. So why bother with the `/Volumes/WhateverTheStartupVolumeIs` part?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Might be an edge case, but when booted into Recovery mode, you can't reference the files using just `/` — you must use a prefix like `/Volumes/volName/...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a more efficient way, but this gets the job done without requiring any third-party tools:

```bash
function bootVolName() {
  diskutil info -plist "$(bless --getBoot)" |
  plutil -extract VolumeName raw -- -
}

$ echo $(bootVolName)
==> MyDisk
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible answer is given below.

```
function bootVolName() {
  diskutil info / | sed -n 's/^ *Volume Name: *//p'
}
```

An example is given below.

```
$ bootVolName
MyDisk
```

This was tested using High Sierra installed on JHFS+ and Catalina installed on a APFS.

Comment: I don't have a non-English system to test with, but searching specifically for `Volume Name` might not work on non-English systems? I think using `plutil` to parse the XML is probably more robust. Also, using hardcoded `/` instead of `bless` means the script could return the wrong info during the time between switching the boot drive via System Prefs up until the system is actually rebooted.

Comment: @luckman212 Are you looking for the name of the volume you're currently booted from, or what's selected as the default startup volume (e.g. in System Preferences)? I (and I think David) assumed it's the first, but you seem to be talking about the second.

Comment: My mistake. I thought you were referring to the volume name with respect to the current running macOS. Your question instead is acting for the current default boot volume. I edited your question to make this more clear.